# Which messaging system for a web dashboard?

Tags: apache-kafka, dashboard, messaging

I would like to make a Web Dashboard system and I am facing a problem. I need to get an information that is in the cache of one of the instances of my program, for this I had thought of doing Pub/Sub with Kafka however I don't know how to do to Publish and get a response from one of my Subscriber. Do you know a pattern that allows this and a service that allows me to do this?

EDIT: I would like to design an infrastructure that follows this pattern:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Attached diagram is showing simple request->response flow, Kafka is designed for different types of architecture, so IMHO you should not focus on Kafka in this case.

However, if you still want to use Kafka for some other reasons I can suggest to you two options:

1. Stick with request->response flow and use [ReplyingKafkaTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#replying-template) or [AggregatingKafkaTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#aggregating-request-reply) to handle it, second one is an extension of first one, this adds functionality to handle more responses then one. You can send a request to Kafka topic from the Dashboard application, then poll the message by one of the Bot instances, next, send reply to reply topic, and then process reply in Dashboard application.
2. Use Kafka to implement [Event-Carried State Transfer pattern](https://martinfowler.com/articles/201701-event-driven.html), move state (mutual guilds data) from Bot Instances directly to Dashboard application via Kafka topic. You can use several tools to implement this:

   - Bot applications send events to Kafka topic via simple KafkaProducer or KafkaTemplate, then use one of the [Kafka Connect sink connectors](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/self-managed/kafka_connectors.html) to save data in Dashboards database.
   - Bot applications send events to Kafka topic via simple KafkaProducer or KafkaTemplate. Run [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) thread in Dashboard application and build a state using Kafka Streams functionalities - grouping, aggregating etc.  Then read the state directly from Kafka Streams internal RocksDB database.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to use Kafka, but I would need a broker message that would allow my dashboard to ask ALL instances of my bot for information

Comment: @FlavioMoreno Have the bots write to a central database. Query the database for "guilds"

Comment: @OneCricketeer The problem is that the data is in the bot's cache so in my server RAM

Comment: @FlavioMoreno Like I said, write to a central, **external** database. Or send events back into Kafka, to do the same, and build a KTable (RocksDB database), as answered.

Comment: I cannot store mutual guilds of all users in persistent, I will have +100M users

Comment: So you like to broadcast request to all Bot Instances and wait until any of them respond?

Comment: @PawełSzymczyk Yes, and I will also have a case where I will wait for an answer from all the instances

Comment: So Aggregating Kafka Template from spring is what you need https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#aggregating-request-reply, I've added it to my response.

Comment: @FlavioMoreno perhaps you're overestimating your initial user base, but databases can easily hold that many rows/documents (and far more).